# Graphical user visualization for Ruby testing

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, cucumber, minitest

What kind of (small) tool can we use in order to render a graphical result from testing?

Actually, I would like to display a graphic instead of this test (for example):

```
Finished in 3.44 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures
```

Maybe a JS graph for instance, where each bugged test could be in red...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Continuous Integration tool such as Hudson you can chart failures over time.

Answer (score 2):

Well Rspec comes with a html formatter. you could just pass the option to command line like

```
rspec -f html -o index.html
```

You could also inherit RSpec formatter to write your own formatters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [fuubar](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/fuubar), it's not JS but shows a nice progress bar in colors. I also use it to have a quick overview of passing or failing tests.